# How to make custom QML component visible?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am quite new to QT and I need to create QML component for viewing web-pages with posibility of tracking click on some links. I created MyWebView class inheritated from QWebView

***mywebview.h***

```
#ifndef MYWEBVIEW_H
#define MYWEBVIEW_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>

class MyWebView: public QWebView {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MyWebView();
public slots:
  void onJavaScriptWindowObjectCleared();
  void trackOpen(QString metadata);
  void trackTurn(QString metadata);
```

***mywebview.cpp***

```
#include "mywebview.h"

MyWebView::MyWebView(){
  connect(this->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),
          this,   SLOT(onJavaScriptWindowObjectCleared()));
  qInfo() << "MyWebView Created";
  }


void MyWebView::onJavaScriptWindowObjectCleared(){
  this->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("console.log('MyWebView init!')");
}

void MyWebView::trackOpen(QString metadata){
        qWarning() << "Open";
}

void MyWebView::trackTurn(QString metadata) {
      qWarning() << "Turn";
}
```

Main program using this component:
***main.cpp***

```
#include "mywebview.h"
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebView/QtWebView>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<MyWebView>("MyWebView", 1, 0, "MyWebView");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/app.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

***app.qml***

```
import MyWebView 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0


ApplicationWindow {
  id: window
  visible: true
  title: "Window"
  width: 640
  height: 480

  MyWebView {
      id: webview
      url: "http://127.0.0.1"
   }
}
```

So, while running this application I can see only clean window and now content inside it. Investigating of local web server's logs (127.0.0.1) I found that program makes requests to web server. How to make my component visible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel? Creating an item as a rectangle is simple but a browser is too complex a task. You must use WebEngineView http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html

Comment: I need to make possible running C++ procedure from javascript on the web page. As I can see WebEngineView allows to run Javascript only, but it's neccessary to calculate statistics inside the C++ app.

Comment: QML can make calls to C++ code so I do not see that that is the problem, if you point out that you want to do exactly I could point out what to do (ie what C++ code you want to do and when you want to call it), QWebView is a Qt Widget that QML can not handle, does not know how to ask you to paint on the window so you can not observe it, QML expects Items, not Qt Widgets.

Comment: My web-page has couple of javascript handlers for events (opening new link, clicking on buttons) and I need to collect statistics in my application from this events including metadata. In other words, javascript function should call C++ procedure in my app with array of data as a param.

Answer (score 0):

Your item needs to be anchored to the parent:

```
MyWebView {
   id: webview
   url: "http://127.0.0.1"
   anchors.fill: parent
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I've got  'Cannot assign to non-existent property "anchors"'

Comment: that is weird. Can you for the sake of at least seeing something assign a `width` and `height`?

Comment: Cannot, 'Invalid property assignment: "width" is a read-only property'